# Factory pattern : Can "definition" be too large?

Tags: c++, factory

Is there disadvantage when "definition of object" that passed into "factory" become (too) big/complex?

### Example

In a game engine, I have a **prototype** class of 3D-graphic object that is quite large, at least for me.

It contains:-

- a pointer(handle) of 3D mesh
- a pointer(handle) of 8 textures (e.g. lambertian, specular)
- colors of 8 textures (e.g. color multiplier)  - 4 floats each
- custom setting for 8 textures - 4 floats each
- ~ 10 boolean flag for blending, depth test, depth write, etc
- (gradually added as the project proceed)

In game logic, I cache some (100?) instances of **prototype** scattering around.  Most of them are stored as fields in many subsystems.
I found that it is also very convenient to store **prototype** by value.

### Question

1. Besides the obvious direct memory/CPU cost, are there any "easy-to-be-overlooked" disadvantage that occur when **prototype** is very big?
2. What are criteria to determine that **prototype** (definition that pass into factory) is *too* big/complex?  What is the remedy/design-pattern that can cure it?
3. Should the **prototype** be stored in business/game logic, by handle/pointer instead?  (I have this idea because people tend to use pointer for large object, but it is a very weak reason.)

Comment: this question is likely to be down-voted/closed because it is too board and primarily opinion-based. are you having an actual problem?

Comment: Currently, no.  But I afraid that there will be, if I still allow it to continue.   I think prevention is better than cure.

Comment: I would suggest you take your suspect code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask for feedback there then. Make sure you [follow this guide](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) before you post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. Besides the obvious direct memory/CPU cost, are there any "easy-to-be-overlooked" disadvantage that occur when prototype is very big?

   *For one graphic object, if you hold it in different places with copies, when you change the object, you have to change all the copies under a lock, or you would met inconsistency issue, which increase the code complexity and potential inconsistency issues.*
2. What are criteria to determine that prototype (definition that pass into factory) is too big/complex? What is the remedy/design-pattern that can cure it?

   *Factory pattern is used for object creation. If you find the logic or code in factory is too complex, the problem should be your object structure not factory pattern.*
3. Should the prototype be stored in business/game logic, by handle/pointer instead? (I have this idea because people tend to use pointer for large object, but it is a very weak reason.)

   *For your case, i recommend P-Impl pattern or smart pointer pattern to store the same object, which could highly reduce the complex and object numbers.*